# React - can't set component's state from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Quite new to react, I'm facing an unexpected behavior.

I'm trying to visualize data that comes from a database with my react app (ChartJS for the data viz)

This is my App.js (I started from `create-react-app`) where I fetch the data from the server's endpoint as a JSON file and I pass it to my BarGraph component:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            records_lst : [],
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData() {
        let data = fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/dbrecords')
            .then((resp) => {
                resp.json().then((res) => {
                    this.setState({
                        records_lst : res,
                    });
                });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (<div className="App">
          <BarGraph
              label1={'Toolbox - whole'}
              label2={'tu-ma'}
              textTitle={'Just a Test'}
              times={this.state.records_lst.length}
          />
        </div>);
    }
}
```

the state records_lst just holds an array of jsons, each of which is one row of the database.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to count how many rows are in the database by counting the length of the `records_lst` array and send it to the BarGraph component (below) to show one single bar with that value, but for some reason, I can't!

Here is the BarGraph:

```
class BarGraph extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        chartData : {
            labels: [this.props.label1],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: [this.props.label2],
                    data: [this.props.times]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What I noticed is that the props of the component are correct, so "times" is calculated correctly, but the state of the component doesn't pick that number.
[Screenshot of Chrome's devtools here for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se4lc.png)

Finally, if in App.js, when I invoke  with all the props, I put `times={44}` (or any other number) the graph shows up normally. I guess for the same reason `label : [this.props.label2]` works too.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(this.props)` in the `BarGraph` constructor?

Comment: its because constructor will get called only once, on the initially rendering of the component that's why state values are not getting updated, so one option is use `getDerivedStateFromProps` or use `componentWillReceiveProps` (if using older version). Another option can be hold the rendering until you get the data from server: `{this.state. records_lst.length && <BarGraph ....`

Comment: @MayankShukla that makes a lot of sense! How do you wait for the server?
where do you put this `{this.state. records_lst.length && <BarGraph ....` and what goes instead of the ... ?

Comment: @AndreaTassera see you are setting the initial value of `records_lst = []`,so length will `0` means `false`, so it will not render the `BarGraph` component, once you get the data from server and do serState it will take the new value (must be non zero), and it will render `BarGraph` after that, means it will render first time and constructor of `BarGraph` will set the correct values.

Comment: @MayankShukla but if `records_lst` was actually `0`, wouldn't it send 0 to the props as well?
While in this case the props are `times: 83` (correctly) but I'm not able to pass this number to the state...
Anyway, I'd try what you are saying, but I don't understand what's the full code and where to put it. Can you help me with some instructions?

Comment: @AndreaTassera check sample working [**code here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/3v46yjx615), if `records_lst` can be zero, so instead of putting check on its length, use a `bool` value like `isDataFetched` with initial value as `false` and update it to `true` once you get the data.

Comment: great, unfortunately we don't have that option. but there will be arrow near the comments you can check that, means useful comments :)

Comment: no change required, it will work in that case also.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
data: [props.times]
```

instead of

```
data: [this.props.times]
```

and the  `constructor` will get called only once and it is when you load your component for the first time since by then you probably wont have the necessary `props` with you since you are getting it asynchronously. so better you use it like this.

```
    componentwillReciveprops(props){
this.setState({data:props.times})
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roopak! I modified the code putting data : [] inside of the state and after the constructor I added this method:
    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.setState({data : props.times})
    }
but now I get an empty list...

Answer (score 0):

@mayak said it correctly above...... the constructor only gets called once

afaik, do not put your props into your state in the constructor.

poll these props inside the render method.

```
class BarGraph extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        var data = {
            chartData : {
                labels: [this.props.label1],
                datasets: [
                    {
                       label: [this.props.label2],
                       data: [this.props.times]
                    }
                ]
            }
        return (
             <div>hello</div>
        }
    }
}
```